# html display:none causes linebreaks

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 clickable images that i want to be hidden, and reappear next to eachother farther into the code. However display:none causes linebreaks and they are placed vertical of eachother.

```
<a href=# onclick="Function1()"><img src ="ImageLink" id="Func1" style="display:none;"></a>
<a href=# onclick="Function2()"><img src ="ImageLink" id="Func2" style="display:none;"></a>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The provided code makes no sense :S

Comment: Please create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) showing the problem. It's not at all clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

Display none causes a change in DOM because the elements are removed .. this could be the reason  .. then you can use  visibility:hidden  .. this has no impact on DOM and only on visibility of the elements

```
style="visibility:hidden;"

style="visibility:visible;"
```

Comment: if i add that to the images, and later remove it, the images seem to become unclickable?

Comment: You have to expicitly set the visibility to default (`visible`) then. But I always though visiblity hides the element while it still takes up space on the displayed page. Which is the opposite from what you want to achieve.

Comment: If you use visibility  you must toogle visibility :hiidden and visibility:visible. You don't need  to remove the image.  simply you show or hide  .the image. In this way the space in the page remain the same only you don't see the image .. Otherwise if you want remove the image then you must build the html element in a way that when you remove component don't break the layout in undesired  way ..

Answer (score 0):

if the only thing you want changed is to prevent wrapping, try this out:

```
<a href=# onclick="Function1()"><img src ="ImageLink" id="Func1" style="display:none; white-space:nowrap;"></a>
```